# Business Central Create new View not displayed in DropDownList

Tags: view, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I am trying to create a new view for Purchase Invoices. I am used this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-views

When I import the extension on my demo tenant successfully, there were no errors while executing the AL Package command and there where no problems to publish and install the extension, the new view is not listed in the dropdown for views on the page.

This is my code for the view:

```
profile BusinessManagerProfile
{
    Caption = 'random caption';
    RoleCenter = "Business Manager Role Center";
    Customizations = PurchaseInvoiceCustomizaton;
}

pagecustomization PurchaseInvoiceCustomizaton customizes "Purchase Invoices"
{
    views
    {
        addfirst
        {
            view(Accounting)
            {
                Visible = true;
                SharedLayout = true;
                Caption = 'name of view';
                Filters = where(Status = filter('released'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am working in an al project that has successfully made pageextensions for subforms, cards and forms, but I am having problems with my pagecustomization.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed your extension on a sandbox, it works ok for me, when I browse to user personalization, in Profile ID dropdown I can see it.

[Screenshot for user customization, profile dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi07I.png)

I think you may have too many wrong customizations, go to Extension management and uninstall things that you don't need, or try it on a fresh demo client.